# How to edit a record of a table and add a record to another table on a page by hitting a submit button in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to edit the information related to a record from one table and add information to another table in a form by pressing the Submit button.

Actually, I want to automatically add a row to another table with each edit

Actually, I want it to be like a "comment for an article", but by pressing the record button, the text of the comment will be added to the comment table and the information of the article will change.

I use the repository model to communicate with the database

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to include an update of the article table as part of the stored procedure to add a new comment.  That way, whenever a comment is added, the associated article has its related properties (comment count, last comment date and time, etc.) updated.  That will ensure those properties are always up to date.

If not using stored procedures, one could execute the two statements independently from a single method in the repository class, but in order to ensure the article table stays updated one would need to add substantial code to undo the comment should the update of the article table fail.